# Show that any finite subset $F$ of $R^n$ is closed by showing that the complement $R^n-F$ is open

Tags: real-analysis

My idea is represent F as a union of {$x_i$} from i to n, and prove each {$x_i$} is closed and by theorem $F$ is closed. But I'm not sure how to show the complement is open.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F = \{x_1,x_2, ..., x_r\}$, suppose by *reductio ad absurdum* that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F$ is not open. Then $\exists$ $x_0$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F$ such that $\forall$ $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists$ $x_{\varepsilon}$ $\in$ $F$ satisfying

$$x_{\varepsilon} \in F \cap B_{\varepsilon} (x_0)$$

where $B_{\varepsilon}(x_0) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n\; |y-x_0|< \varepsilon\}$.

Then for every $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, $\exists x_{i_n} \in F$ such that

$$ x_{i_{n}} \in F \cap B_{1/n} (x_0)$$

This implies that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_{i_n} = x_0$, and every $x_{i_n}$ $\in$ $\{x_1,...,x_r\}= F$.  Defining $$s := \min\{|x_i -x_j|; i,j \in\{1,2,...,r\}\}.$$ 
$\exists$ $k$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, such that 
$$\frac{1}{n}<\frac{s}{2}, \quad \forall n>k $$

Then for every, $n >k$ and $p$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$

$$|x_{i_{n+p}} - x_{i_n} | \leq |x_{i_{n+p}} - x_0| + |x_{i_{n}} - x_0| < s/2 + s/2 = s   $$

Follows from the definition of $s$ that $x_{i_{n+p} } = x_{i_n}$, $\forall$ $p$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, so the sequence $\{x_{i_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is constant $\forall$ $n>k$. Then $x_{i_{k+1}} = x_0$. Absurd! Because $x_0$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus F$ and $x_0 = x_{i_{k+1}}  \in F$. So $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus F$ must be open $\Rightarrow$ $F$ is closed.

Comment: why writing the same answer?? if you have diff approach then its ok!!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $y∈R^n-F$ and fix let $r = \min \{ d(y,x_i) : i = 1,...,n\}$, then clearly $B_{r/2}(y) \subset R^n-F$, thus $R^n-F$ is open and hence $F$ must be closed.

Comment: Could you further explain why do we construct r this way?

Comment: I have given a hint not full answer....a little bit explanation is left try it yourself.